# How is this website getting such good performance? And how can I get it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I'm trying to replicate this "blackhole" effect in Javascript as seen on [i-remember.fr](http://i-remember.fr/en) but I am not getting anywhere NEAR as good performance as them, what am I doing wrong?  I used to have a jQuery selector in my code that ran every animationframe, but I have that removed now which helps out a bunch.  But I'm still running at 40 FPS when their FPS is ridiculously low!

**See their timeline** 
[image]

**And here is mine**
[image]

I would never be able to use mine in actual practice because of the framerate!  Any ideas on what type of sorcery they are using to increase the framerate?

### My Current Engine

---

[View it on CodePen](http://codepen.io/darrylhuffman/pen/MweVGZ?editors=001)

Javascript

```
/*$('.blackhole').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('open_blackhole');
    $(this).toggleClass('close_blackhole');
});*/


// Define Apparatus Variables.
var cw = window.innerWidth,
    ch = window.innerHeight,
    blackhole_entities = {},
    blackhole_entitiesIndex = 0,
    blackhole_entitieAmount = 12000, //6000
    blackhole_button = $('.blackhole'),
    canvas = $('<canvas/>').attr({
        width: cw,
        height: ch,
        id: "apparatus"
    }).appendTo('body'),
    context = canvas.get(0).getContext("2d");

var requestframe = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
    // IE Fallback, you can even fallback to onscroll
    function(callback) {
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60)
    };

// Default Entity "Class"
apparatus.blackhole = function(orbit) {
    blackhole_entitiesIndex++;
    this.id = blackhole_entitiesIndex;
    blackhole_entities[blackhole_entitiesIndex] = this;

    this.width = .5;
    this.height = .5;
    this.orbit = orbit;

    this.velocity = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3200) + 2500);

    this.angle = (Math.PI * 2 / this.width) * Math.floor((Math.random() * cw*4) + 10);;
    var choice = Math.random() * 5;

    var rands = [];
    rands.push(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
    rands.push(Math.random() * 10 + 241);

    var choice2 = Math.random() * 4;

    var rands2 = [];
    rands2.push(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
    rands2.push(Math.random() * 180 + 211);

    this.distance = (rands.reduce(function(p, c) {
        return p + c;
    }, 0) / rands.length);

    this.distance2 = (rands2.reduce(function(p, c) {
        return p + c;
    }, 0) / rands2.length);
    this.increase = Math.PI * 2 / this.width;

    this.distancefix = this.distance;
    this.distance2fix = this.distance2;

    this.color = "255,255,255";
    this.alpha = 0.6

    this.bx = Math.random() * 20 + 1;
    this.by = Math.random() * 20 + 1;
    this.inplace = true;
}

apparatus.blackhole.prototype.draw = function() {
    if (this.orbit >= 2) {
        this.x = this.bx + this.distance * Math.cos(this.angle / this.velocity) + cw / 2;
        this.y = this.by + this.distance * Math.sin(this.angle / this.velocity) + ch / 2;
        this.alpha = 0.6;
    } else {
        this.x = this.bx + this.distance2 * Math.cos(this.angle / this.velocity) + cw / 2;
        this.y = this.by + this.distance2 * Math.sin(this.angle / this.velocity) + ch / 2;
        this.alpha = 0.4;
    }/*
    if (blackhole_button.hasClass('open_blackhole')) {
      blackhole_button.removeClass('close_blackhole');

        if (this.distance >= 171) {
            this.distance = this.distance - 4;
        } else if (this.distance <= 161) {
            this.distance= this.distance + 8;
        }

        if (this.distance2 >= 201) {
            this.distance2 = this.distance2 - 6;
        } else if (this.distance2 <= 161) {
            this.distance2 = this.distance2 + 6;
        }
    }
    if(blackhole_button.hasClass('close_blackhole')){
        if (this.distance >= this.distancefix + 4) {
            this.distance = this.distance - 4;
        } else if (this.distance <= this.distancefix - 5) {
            this.distance= this.distance + 5;
        }

        if (this.distance2 >= this.distance2fix + 10) {
            this.distance2 = this.distance2 - 4;
        } else if (this.distance2 <= this.distance2fix - 10) {
            this.distance2 = this.distance2 + 4;
        }

    }*/

    this.angle += this.increase;

    context.fillStyle = "rgba(" + this.color + "," + this.alpha + ")";
    context.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
}

apparatus.start = function() {
    apparatus('true');
}

apparatus.stop = function() {
    apparatus('false');
}

for (var i = 0; i < blackhole_entitieAmount; i++) {
    new apparatus.blackhole((Math.random() * 5));
}

var mode;
apparatus.spawn_blackhole = function(){
  for (i in blackhole_entities) {
    blackhole_entities[i].draw();
  }
}
function apparatus(mode) {
    if (mode == 'true') {
        var i;
        requestframe(function() {
            context.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);

            apparatus.spawn_blackhole(); 

            apparatus('true');
        });
    }
}

apparatus.start();
```

---

Hopefully someone will have an idea on how I can do this.  I am simply trying to further my knowledge in Javascript canvas manipulation.

**Thanks a bunch for any tips you can throw my way!**

---

*This question might be marked for being a duplicate of my last question, but my last question didn't give me a real, usable framerate.  And due to the fact that the person did "answer" my question, I'm here now.*

Comment: Maybe `getContext("webgl")`?

Comment: getContext("webgl") doesn't support context.fillrect...  Is there any close way to do this in webgl?

Comment: Their website is made using the WebGL context. I strongly recommend using the same if your want to achieve better performances. I myself wrote a Canvas 2d engine in 2012-2013 that was used by major companies, but capped really fast performances-wise due to the canvas 2d limitation. Did a fake-3d explorable galaxy with it once. It took forever to make and fine tune, while I could've done it in a day with webGL libraries like Three.js.